# Hashmap initializing dynamic array of nodes with nullptr c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, hashmap, hashtable

I'm having trouble correctly initializing a dynamic array of nodes with nullptr.

```
HashMap::HashMap(int size)
{

this->sizeOfArray = size;

this->hashArray = new Node*[this->sizeOfArray];
for (int i = 0; i < this->sizeOfArray; i++)
  {
    hashArray[i] = nullptr;

  }

}
```

this is what my 'hashArray' looks like in the header.

```
Node **hashArray;
```

the forloop completes all 500 loops but when I am looking at the data in the array, I can only see the first element before I get 'Unable to read memory'.

Here is an image of what I mean
https://ibb.co/d0GLw9

Here is what Node looks like

```
    Node()
{
    value = 0;
}
Node(std::string input)
{
    key = input;
    value = 1;
    next = nullptr;
}
Node(std::string input, int count)
{
    key = input;
    this->value = count;
    next = nullptr;
}
Node(std::string input, int count, Node *next)
{
    key = input;
    this->value = count;
    this->next = next;
}

Node *next;
std::string key;    
unsigned int value;
```

I suspect this problem is contributing to me not being able to add any new nodes to the hashArray later on.

Answer (score 1):

All of your 500 `Node` pointers are `NULL`, however the type of the `hashArray` is `Node **`, that's why the debugger shows you only one element as if it's a pointer to **one** `Node` pointer. In other words, since your array is dynamic, the debugger doesn't know how many elements to show.

The error you're getting is in regard to viewing the contents of the first `Node` whose pointer is `NULL`, which is naturally can't be read.